# A pronúncia de "faz" em "não faz isso"

Tags: pronúncia

Sabemos que o verbo fazer no imperativo negativo é conjugado da seguinte forma:

- não   faças tu
- não   faça você
- não   façamos nós
- não   façais vós
- não   façam vocês

Embora gramaticalmente errado, em pt-BR falado é comum ouvirmos **"não faz isso!"**.

E foi o que ouvi recentemente, mãe falando com filho: "não faz isso!!!"

Observei então que a frase foi pronunciada como **[não fai-zisso], com a inclusão do som "i" entre o "a" e o "z"**. E percebi também algo que eu nunca havia observado antes, que eu mesmo, quando falo tal frase, também incluo um "i" em "faz".  Se eu quiser dizer de forma enfática "Ele não faz isso!", eu incluirei um "i".

Minha pergunta: Incluir o "i" em "faz" e transferir o "z" para "isso" é a forma mais comum de pronunciar essa frase em pt-BR? E em pt-PT, isso ocorre?  Existe um termo para esse fenômeno em fonética?

Comment: Eu também incluo esse som de i (pt-BR).

Comment: Em pt-PT fazemos o "zisso". O i não - a nossa pronúncia é diferente.

Comment: Eu sou brasileiro (Rio Grande do Sul), e não ditongo dessa maneira. Em Brasília também me parece que é mais exceção do que regra. Mas é característico dos dois falares mais prestigiosos do país, os de São Paulo e Rio de Janeiro (das capitais, bem entendido - os falares caipira e papa-goiaba não gozam de muito prestígio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formação da sílaba /zi/ pelo encadeamento das palavras *faz* e *isso* é um exemplo de um fenómeno típico da **fala encadeada** e mais ou menos universal na língua portuguesa, e a inserção de [j] na palavra “faz” pertence a um tipo de **epêntese** típica de alguns falantes brasileiros, mas não dos portugueses.

### Fala Encadeada

O encadeamento de palavras é conhecido em inglês por ***connected speech***, e aparece como ***fala encadeada*** em vários textos em português. De acordo com a [Wikipedia inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_speech), fala encadeada (“connected speech”) é “em linguística uma sequência contínua de sons formando locuções ou conversas na língua falada.” Explica ainda que na fala encadeada vários sons são modificados de modo que muitas palavras soam diferentes das mesma palavras pronunciadas isoladamente.

Seara, Nunes e Lazzaroto-Volcão ([*Fonética e fonologia do português brasileiro*](http://ppglin.posgrad.ufsc.br/files/2013/04/Livro_Fonetica_e_Fonologia.pdf), UFSC, Florianópolis, 2011, p. 98) mostram esta alteração de sons em ação na palavra *lápis*, alteração essa em tudo idêntica ao que acontece com *faz* (as letras *s* e *z* representam exatamente os mesmos sons em fim de palavra). Do encadeamento de *lápis* e *amarelo* resulta a nova sílaba /za/:

[image]

Se *lápis* for seguido de vogal na palavra seguinte, o *s* é realizado como [z] (como em *ca**s**o* ou *ra**z**ão*) por toda a gente; se for seguido das consoantes surdas /k, f, p/ ou /t/ é realizado como [ʃ] (***ch***á) por quem chia o *s* e como [s] (*ca**ç**a*, *pa**ss**o*) por quem não chia; se for seguido das consoantes sonoras /b, g, l, m, n/ ou /v/ é realizado como [ʒ] (***j***arro) por quem chia o *s* e como [z] por quem não chia.

No princípio ou meio da palavra, estes quatro fonemas—[s], [z], [ʃ] e [ʒ]—identificam palavras diferentes, como por exemplo [s]arro, [z]arro, [ʃ]arro e [ʒ]arro, que se distinguem apenas pelo fonema inicial. Mas em fim de palavra, o falante ignora a diferença entre quaisquer destes quatros sons (se a chegar a notar): na fala encadeada, um daqueles quatro sons é selecionado automática e inconscientemente simplesmente em virtude do som que se segue (e do dialeto). Por isso se diz que em final de palavra estes quatros sons compõem um único arquifonema, representado por /S/.

Não encontrei nenhum termo para a formação de sílaba do /S/ com a vogal inicial da palavra seguinte. Talvez por ser uma coisa corriqueira no português: quando uma consoante faz contacto com uma vogal seguinte, naturalmente forma sílaba com ela. A modificação do som do arquifonema /S/ em função do som seguinte é um caso de assimilação parcial regressiva. O /S/ torna-se mais semelhante ao som seguinte (assimilação); a influência vai do som seguinte para o anterior (regressivo); e o /S/ meramente adquire traços (sonoro ou surdo) do som seguinte (assimilação parcial), em vez de se lhe tornar igual (o que seria assimilação total). Podem ver a terminologia [nesta página do Prof. Paulo Hernandes)](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/glossario/a/assimilacao.html).

### Epêntese

A epêntese é em geral a inserção de um fonema extra numa palavra. Um caso comum no português brasileiro é a inserção da vogal [i] entre duas consoantes, criando uma nova sílaba, como em *ritmo* → *rit[i]mo, advogado* → *ad[i]vogado*. Isto parece resultar de uma aversão a certos encontros consonantais, como *tm, gn, dv, pt*, etc. Esta aversão vem da origem da língua, mas entretanto os portugueses perderam-na.

O nosso caso particular de epêntese vem descrito na [*Fonética e fonologia do português brasileiro*](http://ppglin.posgrad.ufsc.br/files/2013/04/Livro_Fonetica_e_Fonologia.pdf) (p. 115), por [Cantoni (“A epêntese no português brasileiro…”, Gragoatá, Niterói, n. 38, p. 231-246, 2015; p. 233)](http://www.gragoata.uff.br/index.php/gragoata/article/viewFile/403/427), e é estudado, só para o caso do *s* não chiado, por [Peixoto (“Características acústicas do processo de epêntese do glide [j] diante de [s] não-palatalizado” Revista do GEL, São Paulo, v. 8, n. 1, p. 156-171, 2011)](http://www.gel.org.br/revistadogel/volumes/8/gel_8.1_t09_CS.PEIXOTO.pdf). Em qualquer destas publicações, chamam-lhe apenas *epêntese*. Consiste da inserção da semivogal [j] (como em *pa**i**, h**i**ato* ou *ár**e**a*) em sílaba tónica final terminada pelo arquifonema /S/ (na prática, palavras oxítonas terminadas pelas letras *s* ou *z*). O [j] é inserido antes do /S/, fazendo ditongo com a vogal anterior, como por exemplo (links ao Forvo, onde podem escutar estas pronúncias):

> *rapaz* → [*rapa[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/rapaz/#pt), *paz* → [*pa[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/paz/#pt)
>
> *três* → [*trê[j]s*](https://forvo.com/word/tr%C3%AAs/#pt), *dez* → [*de[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/dez/#pt)
>
> *arroz* → [*arro[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/arroz/#pt), *voz* → [*vo[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/voz/#pt)
>
> *luz* → [*lu[j]z*](https://forvo.com/word/luz/#pt)

Quanto à preponderância deste tipo de epêntese, Cantoni (p. 233) diz apenas que ocorre em “alguns dialetos” e que o fenómeno “é marcadamente sujeito a variação dialetal”. Peixoto (p. 156) indica apenas o interior do estado de São Paulo como um exemplo onde esta epêntese ocorre.

Comment: Aplausos de pé !!!

Comment: Em relação ao meu modo de pronunciar, nos sete últimos exemplos só consigo identificar o [i] inserido na palavra "três". (talvez por influência de "dois") Nos exemplos restantes não observo.  Mas certamente muita gente por aqui pronuncia essas palavras com o [i].

Comment: @Centaurus, ao que parece nem todos os que pronunciam assim o fazem sempre ou o fazem sempre com a mesma intensidade. Aliás tu já referes isso. O texto da Peixoto é altamente técnico, mas foi com essa ideia que fiquei. Aliás ando a ouvir [Contos Fluminenses e Histórias da Meia-Noite do Machado de Assis](https://librivox.org/contos-fluminenses-e-historias-da-meia-noite-by-joaquim-maria-machado-de-assis/) (download gratuito), e tenho verificado isso mesmo. Por exemplo em "Aurora sem dia" (49 minutos) aparece muito "rapaz", e o [j] varia entre o quase impercetível e ditongo completo.

Comment: Exatamente!  Talvez eu o faça de modo intermitente, dependendo do momento, em uma fala mais enfática ou mais entusiasmada.

Answer (score 1):

O português do Brasil tem vários sotaques, falares, e até dialetos.  Impossível generalizar, e é difícil saber qual a proporção da população ou dos falares que ‘ditongam’ essa e outras sílabas (‘mais’ em vez de ‘mas’, ‘arroiz’ em vez de ‘arroz’…).

Apesar de ser muito menor, Portugal também tem dialetos, e até um argumento sobre duas línguas, ao se considerar o galego alternativamente outra língua ou um dialeto num sistema dialetal galaico-português.