# Existem sons ligados ou omissões no português informal?

Tags: fonologia

O inglês é um idioma que difere grandemente entre o falado de forma formal e o falado no dia-a-dia.

O português certamente não possui muita diferença, mas ainda sim há sons ligados ou omissões na fala rápida e informal no português?

Por exemplo, no inglês, algumas palavras simplesmente são omitidas em falas mais rápidas, muitas vezes palavras como "this, it, him, them, that, for, of, the, he" simplesmente somem, algumas vezes, duas ou três palavras se tornam um som apenas, no português há estudos que demonstram algo similar?

Comment: Os prtuguezs prnunciam p'aí só mtad das vgais.

Comment: sim, verdade, mas isso é por que eles usam a vogal neutra: schwa, do mesmo modo que o inglês, será que eles fazem uso sons ligados e da omissão de palavras de conteúdo de frase?

Comment: Imagino que estejas a falar de coisas como *carro azul* pronunciado como *carrazul*. Isto todos fazemos. Isto é tangencialmente abordado [nesta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5528/a-pron%c3%bancia-de-faz-em-n%c3%a3o-faz-isso/5544#5544). Na verdade,  é [ɨ], mais elevada que o schwa -- vê [esta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade). Mas mais importante é que muitos ee, ii, oo, uu átonos são pronunciados [ɨ] e depois muitas vezes são simplesmente cancelados na fala rápida >>

Comment: >> vê [esta questão acerca da pronúncia em Portugal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5457/quantas-s%c3%adlabas-tem-a-palavra-menino-em-pt-pt). Depois o r pode desaparecer: *tás semp a queixát* (sempre a queixar-te). E normalmente ninguém pronuncia *te-te* em *portas**te-te** mal*; fica *portást mal*; talvez o último t seja pronunciado com mais força. Não sei se te estou a responder à pergunta aqui nos comentários? (Que não é o lugar das respostas...) A última questão que linkei tem um link a uma exposição sobre a pronúncia de Portugal.

Comment: Obrigado @Jacinto, nós aqui em São Paulo, Brasil, sempre pronunciamos "carro azul" e nunca "carrazul", e "portaste-te" sempre também, mas falamos "bolazul". Me falaram que o Português é um idioma vocálico, o que se escreve é praticamente o mesmo do que se fala, diferente do inglês, se mudamos a pronúncia da palavra, em algum momento teremos que mudar a escrita para adaptar, já no inglês isso não ocorre, eles não vêem necessidade.

Comment: Outros exemplos de omissão sonora que me lembro agora são: "perto de casa" -> "per' de casa", "Belo Horizonte" -> "Bel' 'orizonte", "tu tás fazendo o quê?" ->  "tu tá' fazendo o quê?", "andaste muito, foi?" -> "andas'e muito, foi?"

Comment: @GabrielAraújo, grato pela contribuição, acho que esse é o sotaque mineiro, aqui em São Paulo falamos 'perto de casa' usamos o "o" final bem audível, "Belo Horizonte", nunca subtraímos, mas morei em BH e realmente falam assim como você informou. As outras frases do mesmo modo, não subtraímos, na verdade não usamos tu.

Comment: Nunca estive em Minas, espero muito conhecer, a propósito. O sotaque a que me referí é o de onde moro: Natal.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o objeto desta pergunta não seja a omissão de letras ao se emendar palavras, mas sim a omissão de palavras inteiras, sem a perda do sentido.

Um dos exemplos que consigo pensar, é a omissão de oração subordinada em atos repetitivos, como por exemplo:

- Eu comi uma folha de alface e o boi também comeu uma folha.
- Eu comi uma folha de alface e o boi também comeu uma.
- Eu comi uma folha de alface e o boi também comeu.
- Eu comi uma folha de alface e o boi também.

Veja que esse tipo de supressão de palavras pode gerar ambivalências (ambiguidades); na última frase por exemplo poder-se-ia entender que eu comio boi, além da folha de alface.

Outra forma de supressão de palavras se dá com pronomes

- Devolva-me o doce que pegou sem pedir! (formal)
- Me devolve o doce que pegou sem pedir! (informal)
  (Nota-se a próclise e a conjugação verbal incorreta como marca da informalidade)
- Devolve o doce que pegou sem pedir!
  (Nota-se a supressão total do pronome oblíquo, marca de informalidade)